# Need to modify the edit view in Flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, editview

I am working on Flask admin. Please check the following. [image]

I need to edit the existing record using that edit button shown above.

My edit view is as follow : 
[image]

I need to add a field in edit view whose value appears in the image column shown in the second image.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Just add a field in your data model after the `Image` field.

Comment: I don't want to display it in main view but only in edit page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a field in your data model after the `Image` field.

```
class Restaurant(db.Model):

    # ...
    image = db.Column()
    field_extra = db.Column()
```

In `Flask-Admin`, use `column_list` to specify the field you want to display:

```
class RestaurantModelView(ModelView):

    column_list = ["id", "title", "course", "image"]  # fields list except `field_extra`
```